# GLMs with skewed distributions - why use mean and not mode?

Tags: generalized-linear-model, gamma-distribution, deviance, chi-squared-distribution, mode

There's something that's a bit troubling for me. The unit deviance in GLM is defined as $2[t(y,y) - t(y,\mu)]$, when $t(y,\mu) = y\theta(\mu) - b(\theta(\mu))$ (theta being the natural parameter).

For all GLM's that you encounter, it can be shown that the MLE for the saturated model is always $\hat\mu_i = y_i$ (by simply differentiating and equating to zero). And this means that $t(y,y)$ is the maximum over all possible values of $\mu$.

But this doesn't make much sense to me when it comes to skewed distributions. Consider a $\chi^2_k$ distribution. This is equal to a $\Gamma(\frac{k}{2}, \frac{1}{2})$ distribution. $\mu = k$ for this distribution. Yet if, for some reason we encounter $y_i = 3$, setting $\mu = 4$ will give a much higher PDF (and hence - likelihood) than setting it to equal 3. I suspect this is avoided in GLM because we don't really treat the distribution as Chi-squared, we treat it as Gamma, with $\alpha$, the shape parameter, as constant or as a dispersion parameter. But this feels a bit artificial to me.

My questions are -

1. Why don't we set the **mode** of skewed distributions to be the $y_i$ (instead of the mean)?
2. What happens if I assume my data comes from a Chi-squared distribution with some relations between the mean and some predictor variable. Is that even possible? Will I still be using a Gamma GLM?

UPDATE:

(assuming identity link function) this

[image]

looks more logical to me, than this :

[image]

Comment: Also, consider a power transformation of the data (like Box-Cox). For the case of,a log transforms, it converts a slightly skewed log-normal distribution to a symmetric normal. There are also may be benefits on making the error variance more homogeneous.

Comment: Your post contains multiple questions and contains some unclear claims, which makes it hard to prepare an answer. The chisquare distribution is Gamma, that's just math, not clear why you think that's artificial. Gamma glms are scaled chisquare, not ordinary chisquare, and $\mu$ relates to the scale parameter not the df. Setting $\mu=y$ really does maximise the likelihood, your claim that you can get a higher likelihood value by a different value is incorrect. Setting the mode to be $y$ is not helpful and often it's not even possible, e.g, when the mode is zero.

Comment: @GordonSmyth The GLM analysis of Gamma distributions is using fixed $\alpha$. Chi-Square is Gamma with certain parameters ($\alpha = k/2, \beta = 1/2$), but if you fix alpha, then I'm not sure you still get a chi-square distribution...

Comment: You get a scaled chisquare distribution, see my previous comment.

Comment: Gamma glms assume $y_i \sim \mu_i \chi^2_k / k$ where $\mu_i$ is the mean and the dispersion is $2/k$. This is what I mean by a scaled chisquare, i.e., a chisquare random variable multiplied by a constant.

Comment: @GordonSmyth still, check my update graphs (assuming identity link, and skewed distribution). The mode should have increased likelihood over the mean.

Comment: maybe I can also reduce the question to something more basic (which doesn't necessarily involve GLM): suppose I see one observation (y) from a Chi-Square distribution, but I don't know the parameter (k). Which k will I choose to maximize the likelihood of seeing that observation, k=y (mean) or the k=y+2 (mode)?

Comment: Estimating k (the df) for a chisquare distribution is a straightforward problem but has nothing to do with glms. You could post a new question on that topic if you wish. The maximum likelihood estimate for k is not available in closed form and is not equal to the mean or the mode. I am voting to close this question.

Comment: You can estimate the dispersion and mean of a glm simultaneously by mle and also allow the dispersion to be non-constant using double-glms, see http://www.statsci.org/smyth/pubs/varydisp.html